# Multidimensional version of $f:\mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R, f(x)=f(y) + \int_0^1 \Delta f(sx +(1-s)y)ds (x-y)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am reading a paper in which they use the following lemma.
Let $f:\mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R$ have a continuous first derivative. Then for any $x,y \in \mathbb R^d$,
$$f(x)=f(y) + \int_0^1 \nabla f(sx +(1-s)y)ds  (x-y).$$

Later in the same paper they use a multidimensional version of this lemma. Could someone point out a book where there is a proof of the multidimensional version of this lemma and an example of how can be used?

In the paper, they refer to this formula as Taylor expansion. Why is this a Taylor expansion? why the linear combination inside the argument of the function?

Comment: It is just the one-dimensional version applied to the function $g(t)=f(tx+(1-t)y), 0\leq t \leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks @geetha290krm . But $\nabla f$ is a $d$-dimensional vector. Should I apply the one-dimensional version to every component?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: What do you mean by multidimensional version? If $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^k$, then apply your equality to each component of $f$. Integration is done componentwise, so the equality you get looks exactly the same as in the case $k = 1$, except $\nabla$ needs to be interpreted appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @Mason .  I wrote "multidimensional" because that's what they say in the paper but they mean what you wrote (i.e. $k$>1).